# jQuery make div slide in when scrolling down page

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I want to make a div slide onto my page from the right when a user scrolls down the page (the div will contain a link that takes them back to the top of the page). Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    jQuery('.totop').animate({ right: '0px' });
} else {
    jQuery('.totop').animate({ right: '-300px' });
}
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.totop {
position:fixed;
bottom:50%;
right:-300px;
width:300px;
height:100px;
font-size:30px;
color:white;
background:#f18500;
}
```

The Div is behaving very oddly, when I scroll down the div takes about 5 seconds to appear, then it comes into view but looks like it is making several attempts to slide off again before remaining still, when I slide back to the top it dissapears...but after about 5 seconds again. Would love some help to find out what is wrong with my code please.

Comment: check this article for creating a scroll to the top of the page: http://recentsolutions.net/web-development/smooth-scroll/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your animations are getting queued, use `.stop()`:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        if (jQuery('.totop').hasClass('visible') == false) {
            jQuery('.totop').stop().animate({
                right: '0px'
            }, function () {
                jQuery('.totop').addClass('visible')
            });
        }
    } else {
        if (jQuery('.totop').hasClass('visible') == true) {
            jQuery('.totop').stop().animate({
                right: '-300px'
            }, function () {
                jQuery('.totop').removeClass('visible')
            });
        }
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/MkJwm/

Comment: It wasn't good enough, I updated my answer. Once the slide was visible and you keep scrolling down, the animation started again. Now it gets shown only once.

Comment: I like this so much. But, is there a way for visitor to click it to close it if they don't wanna see the div?

Comment: @Jornes Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/10dL7jb6/. There is a toggle button with which you can hide and show the div. When hidden, a small bit of the div is still visible for toggle possibility. If you get under 100px from top, the div is never visible.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('#div-to-show').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        $('#div-to-show').slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

Not tested.

Comment: It's not the question about slide up/down!

Comment: This doesn't work for me with bootstrap anyways because the navbar just dissapears really quickly and appears no matter what speed I set it at. I think the consistent movement of the screen matters.